# Passing a variable into a function and then to a class

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and had made a script which displays random songs from a JSON file. It was working fine, but I thought that I'd venture into the world of classes to make parts of it reusable.

Now I can't get the class to present the random result.

This is the class which I also use when I want to play a specific song:

```
songid = int()

class songDetails():
    def __init__(self, songId, songName, artist, key, mode, tempo, proficiency, uuid) -> None:
        self.songId = songId
        self.songName = songName
        self.artist = artist
        self.key = key
        self.mode = mode
        self.tempo = tempo
        self.proficiency = proficiency
        self.uuid = uuid
        
    def songCard(self):
        # songId = random
        print(f"{self.songId}")
        print(f"{self.songName}, by {self.artist}")
        print(f"Key: {keys[self.key]}{modes[self.mode]}")
        print(f"BPM: {self.tempo}")
        print(f"{proficiencyLevel[self.proficiency]}\n")
```

Because I had so many JSON references throughout the script, I decided to build a function that stored each as a variable

```
def readSongsJSON():
    # songId = randomSong()
    try:
        global songId
        songsJSON = pd.read_json(data)
        songItems = songsJSON['songbook']['songs']
        songAllInfo = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]
        songName = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['song']
        songArtist = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['artist']
        songKey = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['key']
        songMode = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['mode']
        songTempo = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['tempo']
        songKeyConfidenceAvg = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['keyConfidenceAvg']
        songProficiency = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['proficiency']
        songUUID = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['uuid']
        songCategory = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['category']
        songSpotifyURI = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['spotifyURI']
        songVideo = songsJSON['songbook']['songs'][songId]['video']
    except:
        print("Cannot access data ")

    return songItems, songAllInfo, songName, songArtist, songKey, songMode, songTempo, songKeyConfidenceAvg, songProficiency, songUUID, songCategory, songSpotifyURI, songVideo
```

Finally, this is the function that is triggered from a Typer command:

```
def randomSong():
    # Open JSON file

    songItems, songAllInfo, songName, songArtist, songKey, songMode, songTempo, songKeyConfidenceAvg, songProficiency, songUUID, songCategory, songSpotifyURI, songVideo = readSongsJSON()
    randomSong = random.choice(songItems)
    randomUUID = randomSong['uuid']

    songIterator = 0
 
    for x in songItems:
        if randomUUID == songItems[songIterator]['uuid']:
            song = songDetails(
                songId,
                songName,
                songArtist,
                songKey,
                songMode,
                songTempo,
                songProficiency,
                songUUID
                )
                 # DISPLAY THE SONG CARD
                 song.songCard()
            break
        else:
            songIterator += 1
    # print(songIterator)
```

I guess my challenge is, how do I get the random `songID` to be assigned to the content in `readSongsJSON` and then displayed in the Class output?

I've tried a range of options, but the `songId` always stays as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current structure is

0. A class to print the info of the random song
1. A function to load all songs, and get the info of a song based on songId (global variable)
2. A function to get a random song from list of all songs, and use iterations to find the song information, if it matches, run **class in step 0** to print the info of the song

Seem like you are squeezing 2 functions in step 1, but the latter function (get the info of a song) should come after selecting a random songId in step 2. You can do

0. A class to print the info of the random song
1. A function to load all songs
2. A function to get the info of a song based on songId
3. A function to get a random song from list of all songs, run **function in step 2** to get the info of the song, run **class in step 0** to print the info of the song

```
class songDetails():
    def __init__(self, songId, songName, artist, key, mode, tempo, proficiency, uuid) -> None:
        self.songId = songId
        self.songName = songName
        self.artist = artist
        self.key = key
        self.mode = mode
        self.tempo = tempo
        self.proficiency = proficiency
        self.uuid = uuid
        
    def songCard(self):
        # songId = random
        print(f"{self.songId}")
        print(f"{self.songName}, by {self.artist}")
        print(f"Key: {keys[self.key]}{modes[self.mode]}")
        print(f"BPM: {self.tempo}")
        print(f"{proficiencyLevel[self.proficiency]}\n")
```

```
def readSongsJSON():
    try:
        songsJSON = pd.read_json(data)
        songItems = songsJSON['songbook']['songs']
    except:
        print("Cannot access data ")
    return songItems

def readSongInfo(songId, songItems):
    songAllInfo = songItems[songId]
    songName = songAllInfo['song']
    songArtist = songAllInfo['artist']
    songKey = songAllInfo['key']
    songMode = songAllInfo['mode']
    songTempo = songAllInfo['tempo']
    songKeyConfidenceAvg = songAllInfo['keyConfidenceAvg']
    songProficiency = songAllInfo['proficiency']
    songUUID = songAllInfo['uuid']
    songCategory = songAllInfo['category']
    songSpotifyURI = songAllInfo['spotifyURI']
    songVideo = songAllInfo['video']
    return songAllInfo, songName, songArtist, songKey, songMode, songTempo, songKeyConfidenceAvg, songProficiency, songUUID, songCategory, songSpotifyURI, songVideo
```

```
def randomSong():
    # Open JSON file
    songItems = readSongsJSON()

    # randomly select a songId
    songId = random.choice(range(len(songItems)))
    
    # get the info of the song
    songAllInfo, songName, songArtist, songKey, songMode, songTempo, songKeyConfidenceAvg, songProficiency, songUUID, songCategory, songSpotifyURI, songVideo = readSongInfo(songId, songItems)

    song = songDetails(
        songId,
        songName,
        songArtist,
        songKey,
        songMode,
        songTempo,
        songProficiency,
        songUUID
        )
    # DISPLAY THE SONG CARD
    song.songCard()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving that @wavetitan !
So the issue was a rookie mistake of using variables before assigning the value to it.
I really appreciate it.

Comment: As a side question, is better than receiving function returns than by listing them out?

I.e. not using `songAllInfo, songName, songArtist, songKey, songMode, songTempo, songKeyConfidenceAvg, songProficiency, songUUID, songCategory, songSpotifyURI, songVideo = readSongInfo(songId, songItems)
 `?

Comment: @StevenDiffey it is not necessary to use a function. Functions are to help break the program into smaller and modular chunks.